# kafka: error while consuming TestTopic/0: kafka server: Request exceeded the user-specified time limit in the request

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, google-cloud-pubsub, benthos

Helo,

**"kafka: error while consuming TestTopic/0: kafka server: Request exceeded the user-specified time limit in the request."**

I am getting the above error intermittently while consuming from kafka broker(i.e kafka) OR GCP Pub Sub(i.e gcp_pubsub) pubsub on topic "TestTopic" via Benthos kafka input configuration as below(for input kafka):

```
input:
  broker:
    inputs:
      - kafka:
          addresses:
            - ${KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS:localhost:9092}
          topics: 
            - TestTopic
          client_id: clientIdTest
          consumer_group: consumerGroupTest
          checkpoint_limit: 2000
          batching:
            count: 1000
            byte_size: 10485760
            period: "1s"
```

Comment: Have you tried using https://www.benthos.dev/docs/components/inputs/gcp_pubsub as input? I’m not very familiar with GCP PubSub, but if it’s fully compatible with the Kafka API, then maybe you need to tweak some settings, like `group.session_timeout`. See the Advanced tab [here](https://www.benthos.dev/docs/components/inputs/kafka). Lastly, try the [kafka_franz](https://www.benthos.dev/docs/components/inputs/kafka_franz) input, which works just like `kafka`, but it uses the [franz-go](https://github.com/twmb/franz-go) library instead of Shopify’s [sarama](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mihai,

Yes, it is happening for both inputs that consume from kafka broker(i.e kafka) and GCP Pub Sub(i.e gcp_pubsub).

Ok, i will try to increase the group.session_timeout from 10s(default) to some prefeable say 40s and will let you know.

Regarding kafka_franz, i saw that it is in experimental state and they said "This component is experimental and therefore subject to change or removal outside of major version releases.", so i donot thing
that it is a good idea to use it in production, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I’m a contributor to the project and I don’t think there’s any reason to remove kafka_franz. If you still experience issues, then please provide some means of replicating the issue. Also feel free to reach out to the maintainer via https://benthos.dev/community

Comment: Hi  Mihai,

We tweak the group.session_timeout from 10s(default) to 100s but still we are getting the same issue, FYI: we are publishing 350 messages/second for 30 min on TestTopic having 8 partitions, and error is happening on each partitions on exact same time. Any suggestions...............?

Comment: Bummer. Try joining the community as I mentioned above and provide some means of reproducing the issue.